# Update width or height of open Angular Material 2 dialog

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

Is there a method to change the width (or height) of an open Angular Material 2 dialog?

The closest I got was getting a reference to the dialog and calling the `updateSize` method from within the dialog. Though I don't think the dialog reference method works in this way.

I use a dialog to capture and submit form data. Based on the response, success or error, the content within the dialog updates. It is at this point I would like to reduce the width of the dialog.

I have installed `Angular v4.2.4` and `Angular Material 2 v2.0.0-beta.12`

Happy to provide additional information or code examples if needed. Or to consider a different approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was on the right track. I just had the arguments wrong.

To update the width or height of an open dialog, you get a reference to the open dialog and call the `updateSize` method. The first parameter sets the width and the second parameter sets the height. Both are of type `string`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dialog',
  templateUrl: './my-dialog.component.html'
})
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    private shouldSizeUpdate: boolean;

    constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>,
                @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any) {
        this.shouldSizeUpdate = data.shouldSizeUpdate;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.shouldSizeUpdate) this.updateSize();
    }

    updateSize() {
        this.dialogRef.updateSize("300px", "500px");
    }

}
```

And the code for further reference.

```
     /**
     * Updates the dialog's width and height.
     * @param {?=} width New width of the dialog.
     * @param {?=} height New height of the dialog.
     * @return {?}
     */
    MatDialogRef.prototype.updateSize = function (width, height) {
        if (width === void 0) { width = 'auto'; }
        if (height === void 0) { height = 'auto'; }
        this._getPositionStrategy().width(width).height(height);
        this._overlayRef.updatePosition();
        return this;
    };
```

Comment: To manipulate width only  this.dialogRef.updateSize("50%"); or width and height   this.dialogRef.updateSize("50%", "60%");

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the params avilable in [MatDialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) which provides `height`, `width`, `max-height`, and `max-width` params. These params are passed as an object to the `open` method.

So you can do something like:

```js
    let dialogRef = dialog.open(MyComponent, {
      height: '400px',
      width: '600px',
    });
```

Comment: This sets the size of the dialog on open. I would like to be able to change the size of the dialog after is has already been opened as the content changes. I have now found the answer to this and will post. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @bmd Use can use the logic to update the size before dialog.open is called and then set size in MatDialogConfig. As you are only calling updateSize from ngOnInit, it will be updating size only once at initialization. Using MatDialogConfig is preferred one.